# lxml xpath extracts nothing

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to extract the text Rally with xpath from the tags in flickr. But after fiddling with this for ages, I can't get it to work. It just scrapes nothing. Hoping someone can see what I am doing wrong.

```
# encoding=utf-8

from lxml import html
import requests


page = requests.get('https://www.flickr.com/photos/128712066@N03/23984506813/in/pool-kuruma/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

rally = tree.xpath(u'//*[@id="yui_3_16_0_1_1454875001812_24199"]/ul//a[2]/a/text()')

print rally
```

Comment: Bbecause the id tag `yui_3_16_0_1_1454875001812_24199` does not exist. What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: In the bottom part of the website there is the tag system for tagging images. I wanted to get the text from specific tags, and use them in a bigger project. I suppose this xpath is better? I can't seem to get it working either : / though 'html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/ul//a[2]/a/text()

Comment: It is not in  the source, it is generated by javascript.

Comment: You might be better using the api https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flickrapi

Comment: Alright, wow, thanks! So trying this way to simply get the text with xpath and lxml was wrong. Some searching and I think I can get around this by using scrapy and scrapy-splash middleware for the javascript [link](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash) Any other site or method you could nudge me towards? edit: Saw your latest comment just now, that link looks great! Thanks.

Comment: I have used splash, it is easy to use but if you can use the api I would definitely go down that route